# angular 2 variable undefined

Tags: variables, angular, undefined

I have this piece of code in my angular2 project:

```
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {Component, AfterViewInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {DROPDOWN_DIRECTIVES} from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';

@Component({
    selector: '<aInsertTable></aInsertTable>',
    templateUrl: './app/templates/insertTable/insertTable.html',
    directives: [DROPDOWN_DIRECTIVES],
})
export class InsertTableComponent implements AfterViewInit { 
    public status:{isopen:boolean} = {isopen: false};
    public sel: any;
    public rng: any;

    ngAfterViewInit(){
        jQuery('#editable-area').keyup(function(){
            this.sel = window.getSelection();
            this.rng = this.sel.getRangeAt(0);
        })
        jQuery('#editable-area').mouseup(function(){
            this.sel = window.getSelection();
            this.rng = this.sel.getRangeAt(0);
            console.log(this.sel);
            console.log(this.rng);
        })
    }

    public toggleDropdown($event:MouseEvent):void {
        this.status.isopen = !this.status.isopen;
    }

    insertTable(x, y) {
        console.log(this.sel);
        console.log(this.rng);
        if (!$tableId) {
            var $tableId = 0;
        }

        var table = document.createElement("Table");
        table.id = "table" + $tableId;
        table.className = "dynamic-table table";
        $tableId++;

        for (var i = 0; i < y + 1; i++) {
            var tr = document.createElement('tr');
            for (var j = 0; j < x + 1; j++) {
                var td = document.createElement('td');
                tr.appendChild(td);
            };
            table.appendChild(tr);
        };

        this.rng.insertNode(table);
    }
}
```

Now, here's the problem:

when I click or type in the editable area, I see the `sel` and `rng` values in my console, so they are being set, but, they seem to be available only to the `ngAfterViewInit` function scope cause when I try inserting a table I get both `sel` and `rng` as undefined. Can someone help me figuring out what I'm doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use arrow function in your keyup and mouseup callbacks like this

```
jQuery('#editable-area').keyup(() => {
  this.sel = window.getSelection();
  this.rng = this.sel.getRangeAt(0);
})

jQuery('#editable-area').mouseup(() => {
  this.sel = window.getSelection();
  this.rng = this.sel.getRangeAt(0);
  console.log(this.sel);
  console.log(this.rng);
})
```

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Lexical_this

Comment: Could you give an explanation about what is the difference between `function()` and `()=>`? can't seem to find one. Thank you.

Comment: You could find great explanation of this behavior arrow function on this page https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Lexical_this